# Certificate validation failed

Tags: asp.net, wcf, certificate, wcf-security

**Actors**

-Asp.net site - Client 
-Wcf services - Server

Both applications runs on IIS-7.

I want to make integration test between the two applications. The client access the Server through 'https'. 
I have created a certificate and assigned it to the server. I also added the certificate to the 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' to be considered a valid certificate. When I 'hit' the server's services through my browser (IE, chrome...) the certificate appears to be valid. But when my client application tries to access the server then I get the following error:

```
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority **** --->
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Is there any way to skip the validation procedure or to make the certificate valid for my client application?

Just to know: 

1. I cannot purchase a certificate because I will only use it for testing purposes.

2. I cannot make any changes on any of the application's code (server-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to figured it out.

The problem was a previous (expired) certificate with the same name that was already added to the *'Trusted Root Certification Authorities'*. Every time I was installing my new certificate through the *'Certificate Import Wizard'* (or through MMC) the wizard informed me that it was successfully added. However, it was keeping the instance of the previous certificate without overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the validation callback to always return true:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => true;
```

Or does that violate the 'no changes to code' condition?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it violates that condition. The only change (if this is considered a change) I can make is on the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the certificate into your trusted root store?

If you went through a browser to do it, most likely you only added it to the current user. Try adding it through the MMC snap-in for the Local Computer Account instead; this is where we install our self-signed IIS Express certificates and WCF seems happy with them.

Comment: I have added it through MMC on my local computer and on the Web Server were the both applications run. Before that change the browsers were 'complained' about the certificate. After that, it seems to be valid but still my client's validation procedure fails.